# DownloadFileAsync not downloading file

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write simple app which downloads one file from web.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        Uri uri = new Uri("http://download.thinkbroadband.com/100MB.zip");

        // Specify that the DownloadFileCallback method gets called
        // when the download completes.
        client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(DownloadFileCallback2);
        // Specify a progress notification handler.
        client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(DownloadProgressCallback);
        client.DownloadFileAsync(uri, "serverdata.txt");

        Console.WriteLine("Download successful.");

    }
    private static void DownloadProgressCallback(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Displays the operation identifier, and the transfer progress.
        Console.WriteLine("{0}    downloaded {1} of {2} bytes. {3} % complete...",
            (string)e.UserState,
            e.BytesReceived,
            e.TotalBytesToReceive,
            e.ProgressPercentage);
    }
    private static void DownloadFileCallback2(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Displays the operation identifier, and the transfer progress.
        Console.WriteLine("Download complete");
    }
}
```

I put break point in this line: `Console.WriteLine("Download complete");` but its never hit. Program creates empty `serverdata.txt` file. I receive no updates in console about download % from `DownloadProgressCallback`. What I did wrong?

Comment: Your program exits immediately after starting the download. You have to keep it alive until the download is completed.

Comment: Instead of `Console.WriteLine("Download successful.");`, write `Console.ReadLine();`

Comment: You use async so that you can do other things while the download is going.  Exiting the program is not one of the other things you can do :)

Comment: why dont you try to catch exception at downloadAsync() and increase timeout

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I haven't tried this but you can try using [`IsBusy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.isbusy(v=vs.110).aspx) property :

```
while(client.IsBusy)
     Thread.Sleep(1000);

Console.WriteLine("Download successful.");
```

OR, use [`WebClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193917(v=vs.110).aspx) method if you are using .NET 4.5

```
client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(uri, "serverdata.txt").Wait();
Console.WriteLine("Download successful.");
```

Answer (score 1):

As men tioned by others using `DownloadFileTaskAsync` an make your life easier when it comes to waiting for the completion of the task. You can either `await` the result asynchronously or  call `Wait()` to do a blocking wait.

Here is the code:

```
private static void DownloadProgressCallback(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Displays the operation identifier, and the transfer progress.
        Console.WriteLine("{0}    downloaded {1} of {2} bytes. {3} % complete...",
            ((TaskCompletionSource<object>)e.UserState).Task.AsyncState,
            e.BytesReceived,
            e.TotalBytesToReceive,
            e.ProgressPercentage);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        Uri uri = new Uri("http://download.thinkbroadband.com/100MB.zip");

        // Specify a progress notification handler.
        client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(DownloadProgressCallback);
        var task = client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(uri, "serverdata.txt"); // use Task based API

        task.Wait(); // Wait for download to complete, can deadlock in GUI apps

        Console.WriteLine("Download complete");

        Console.WriteLine("Download successful.");
    }
```

The `Wait()` call can deadlock on a GUI based app, but it's fine for your case.